# MySQL: "Ignore" if a table row is missing during JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm doing a LEFT JOIN on three tables, where the table "time" doesn't necessarily contain any matching rows. But if no matching rows is found in that table, the linked data disappears.

```
SELECT
    w.date AS worker_date,
    w.name AS worker_name,
    w.address AS worker_address,
    w.zip AS worker_zip,
    w.place AS worker_place,
    w.phone AS worker_phone,
    w.email AS worker_email,
    w.company AS worker_company,
    w.accessibility AS worker_accessibility,
    c.date AS client_date,
    c.name AS client_name,
    c.address AS client_address,
    c.zip AS client_zip,
    c.place AS client_place,
    c.phone AS client_phone,
    c.email AS client_email,
    c.web AS client_web,
    c.contact AS client_contact,
    j.date AS job_date,
    j.client_id,
    j.worker_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    j.description AS job_description,
    j.type AS job_type,
    j.status AS job_status,
    j.proof AS job_proof,
    j.deadline AS job_deadline,
    j.price AS job_price,
    j.final_client AS job_final_client,
    SUM(t.hours) AS time_hours
FROM
    jobs AS j
LEFT JOIN (
    workers AS w,
    clients AS c,
    time AS t
) ON (
    w.id = j.worker_id AND
    c.id = j.client_id AND
    j.id = t.job_id
) GROUP BY
    j.id;
```

How can I make this work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to clarify this - in case no match happens with `time` table what value should come in `time_hours`

Comment: @sandeepan: Then I want a zero as time_hours, and not a whole missing record.

Comment: are you sure the whole record was missing? You are using left join and records should not get missed if no match happens with `time` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>add</strike>

`WHERE t.job_id IS NOT NULL` before `GROUP BY`

Try Replace

`SUM(t.hours) AS time_hours`

to

`(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t.hours),0) FROM time WHERE time.job_id=j.job_id) AS time_hours`

And remove the time from the join

Comment: Hm, now it removed that entry from the result completely.

Comment: Thought I already had tested that, but apparently not - it works! Is inner selections a valid solution or just a walk-around in this case?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. If you don't need table for some constraints checking, you probably should skip joining the table. You can use the explain to SQL, and if you have mysql greater than version 5.0.37, you can check the query speed using profiling - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

Comment: @ajreal why is it needed to remove the table `time` from the join?

Comment: @ajreal ok understood, you are doing the condition check in the subquery. That will also give correct results

Comment: @sandeepan: As it isn't used in his code it's just unnecessary to keep it.

Comment: @Ivarska yes I already understood that, but performance wise my solution may be better. You may check the query timings

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic query is correct (with the join under braces)

Just replace

```
SUM(t.hours) AS time_hours
```

with

```
SUM(if(t.hours is NULL,0,t.hours)) AS time_hours
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem here, but the behavior of commas vs JOINs changed after a certain MySQL version. Try this

```
 ...
 FROM jobs AS j LEFT JOIN workers AS w ON w.id = j.worker_id
 LEFT JOIN clients AS c c.id = j.client_id
 LEFT JOIN `time` AS t ON j.id = t.job_id
 ...
```

Also modify the SUM with IFNULL as @ajreal suggests.